# Count reset to 0 if reached a certain condition

Tags: sql, database, presto

The following example demonstrates the case:
[image]

Following is the sample data:

[image]

Following is the output expectation (note that there are more than 1 entities in the 'entity' column):

[image]

- is_hit is defined when variable a is <=4
- variable_a is defined if the total hit from the past days have reached 3

What I have to do is to tag whether the entity has a cumulative hit reached a total count of 3. Once the entity is tagged, the hit count should reset to 0 again.
By following this logic, looking at the demonstration above the Entity A tagged on 4th June and 9th June.

Currently, my issue is applying the is_tagged logic to the query. Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: I'm confused.  Is there a "hit count" in the data?  You show it in the first image but not in the sample data.

Comment: Your screenshots looks like Excel, did you've used the wrong tags?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, the 'hit count' is only to demonstrates the cumulative hit counts @GordonLinoff.

Comment: Nope, I used excel just to make a simple demonstration of the case I'm facing @H.Pauwelyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when is_tagged and
                  mod(row_number() over (partition by entity, is_tagged
                                         order by date
                                        ),
                       3) = 0
             then true
        end)
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that your columns are booleans.  If they are strings then use `'true'`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry for the confusion before though. I've updated my question and this seems doesn't answer my question.  What I need is to count the is_hit = true column and if it reached the total count of 3 then it will be tagged in the is_tagged column. Also once it is tagged, the count will start from 0 again as demonstrated in the first picture

Comment: @doo . . . Right.  You don't just want the first one.  You can use `mod()`.